# How to use html's <span> into {{ variable accessor }}

Tags: html, django, html-table

I am Building a BlogApp and I am stuck on an Error.

**What i am trying to do**

I am trying to access `<div>Place: <span id="place"></span></div>` into `{{ place }}` or `{% if place %}`

my_templtae.html

```
<script>

$.ajax({
  url: "https://geolocation-db.com/jsonp",
  jsonpCallback: "callback",
  dataType: "jsonp",
  success: function(location) {
    $('#place').html(location.place);
  }
});

</script>

<div>Place: <span id="place"></span></div>
```

**The Problem**

It is not accessing when i insert it in `{{ place}}`

I don't know what to do.

Any help would be Appreciated.

Thank You in Advance

Comment: Got any errors in the browser console?

Comment: No, Nothing is showing.

Comment: AND i want to do it this way `{{ }}.`

Comment: if you are trying to pass context from js to templates the answer is no, you can't pass data from js to the template, since the js is rendered on the client-side and templates are rendered on the server.

Comment: No Possibilities ?

Comment: you cant use ```{{ }}``` here, btw your script should work, that is the right way of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

Your Js script should work, it seems like you haven't triggered the function, so you have to wrap your js snippet inside a `$(document).ready(function())` this will trigger the script when the page loads.

Update: the response object `location` has no object `place`, you can use `city` instead of the `place`

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $.ajax({
    url: "https://geolocation-db.com/jsonp",
    jsonpCallback: "callback",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    success: function(location) {
      $('#place').html(location.city);
    }
  });
});
</script>
```